# Designing slide show like application

Tags: blackberry

i am new to black berry,i want an application like slideshow,how can i display different images in single fieldmanager one by one as bitmap field

Answer (score 0):

BitmapField might be a good place to start looking.  It provides a method that allows you to set the current bitmap to display.  Here's the javadocs:

[BitmapField JavaDocs](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/BitmapField.html)

The design details of how you manage the slides in the slide show could be done in many ways.  A simple example would be to have a Vector of the image filenames in the slide show and when the user performs whatever action you define to traverse through the slides, you could reference the array, load the image and then set it as the active image in your BitmapField.  How you accomplish that part is up to you.  But, you need to keep in mind that you're memory isn't infinite and you can't predict how large a slideshow you may need to support.

Answer (score -1):

Take a HorizontalFieldManager for displaying the image Horizontally, add all the BitmapField in the HorizontalFieldManager.

Comment: That doesn't scale very well. You could have hundreds of Images loaded at once with that implementation.